# How to determine service provider connected app in Login page?

Tags: apex, lightning, oauth2, single-sign-on, identity-provider

I have a setup where Salesforce is the Identity provider and the authorization flow is service-provider initiated (where the service provider supports oAuth, not SAML). The login page is reached and the redirect back is provided by the `/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage` which is set as the startUrl. Now we are introducing a second service provider (of the same system, so oAuth only) and the URLs that are in the community must point correctly depending on which system initiated the oAuth process. Is there any way to determine the callback URL from the login page? I have thought of a workaround using the Experience ID but it is not really meant for that and could actually be modified by the end-user (so it is not reliable). Any ideas of how this information can be captured on page load?

We would have 2 different connected apps, so if we could distinguish which one initiated the login process, that would solve the issue.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to build dynamic URLs based on the connected app used to invoke this oAuth process. They are links in the header component and depending on the callbackUrl they should point to a different instance/site of commerce cloud. Because I don't have context of which connected app was used I can't build the URLs.